# Equivalent properties for a kind of relative compactness?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y \subseteq X$.

Consider the following statements:

(i) Every net in $Y$ has a cluster point in $X$.

(ii) Every infinite subset of $Y$ has a complete accumulation point in $X$.

These are two possible definitions for relative compactness of $Y$ in $X$.

Question 1: Is there some relation between (i) and (ii)? Does it hold (i) $\Leftrightarrow$ (ii)?

I'm unfamiliar with the formal set theoretical considerations, but I would try to "prove" as follows.

"(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)": Let $Z \subseteq Y$ infinite and let $\alpha$ denote the least ordinal such that $|\alpha| = |Z|$ (for which it then follows that $\alpha = |\alpha|$ when cardinals are represented by ordinals), i.e. we have a bijection $x : \alpha \to Z$ which gives us a net $x_a$ such that $\{ x_a \mid a \in A \} = Z$. Now $x_a$ has a cluster point $x \in X$ and show that $x$ is a complete accumulation point of $Z$. Herefore, let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. We know that $x_a$ is frequently in $U$ which means that for each $a_0 \in \alpha$ there is $a \geq a_0$ such that $x_a \in U$. But from this fact, I do not see, why it should hold that $|U \cap \{ x_a \mid a \in A \}| = |U|$. (Why cannot it be the case that if $x_a \in U$ for some $a$ and all $x_b \not\in U$ for $b < a$ that we get a gap in the cardinality? Does it has to do something with the fact that a strictly decreasing sequence of ordinals stabilizes after finitely many steps?)

"(ii) $\Rightarrow$" (i): Let $(x_a)_{a \in A}$ be a net in $Y$ and set $Z := \{ x_a \mid a \in A \}$. If $Z = \{ y_1, \dots, y_n \}$ is finite then some point $y_k \in Z$ is a cluster point. (If not, then for each $k$ there exists an open neighborhood $U_k$ of $y_k$ and $a_k \in A$ such that for all $a \geq a_k$ it holds $x_k \not \in U_k$. Since $A$ is directed the finite set $\{ a_1, \dots, a_k \}$ has an upper bound $s$ and it follows that $x_s \not \in \bigcup_k U_k$ which is a contradiction.) So assume that $Z$ is infinite. Then $Z$ has a complete accumulation point $x \in X$. If $x$ is not a cluster point of $x_a$ then there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and $a_0 \in A$ such that for all $a \geq a_0$ it holds $x_a \not\in U$. However, we have that $|U \cap Z| = |Z|$ which implies $|U \cap \{ x_a \mid a < a_0 \}| = | \{ x_a \mid a \in A \}|$, so I have a bijection of $\{ x_a \mid a \in A \}$ onto its subset $U \cap \{ x_a \mid a < a_0 \}$. So our situation is as follows: We have a partition $Z = Z_1 \cup Z_2$ with $Z_1 := \{ x_a \mid a \geq a_0 \} \subseteq X \setminus U$ and $Z_2 := \{ x_a \mid a < a_0 \} \cap U$ such that $Z$ and $Z_2$ have the same cardinality, and thus $|Z_1| \leq |Z_2|$. I do not see any possible contradiction.

Question 2: So if there is no relation between (i) and (ii) are there some relations to other relative compactness properties (e.g. $\overline{Y}$ is compact or $Y$ is contained in a compact subset)?

Comment: In the first "proof", "cofinality" of cardinals is the concept you're looking for.

Comment: Of course $Y$ being contained in a compact subset of $X$ will imply (ii) and (i), by standard facts.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sure, (iii) $:\Leftrightarrow$ "$Y$ is contained in a compact subset" implies (i) (and thus (ii) by Brian M. Scott's) answer) in any topological space, but (i) does not imply (iii) in general and not even in a $T_2$ space. However, (i) implies (iv) $:\Leftrightarrow$ "$\overline{Y}$ is compact" (and thus (iii)) in a $T_3$ space. Thus (ii) does not in general imply (iii) or (iv). So if (ii) is strictly weaker than (i) it is interesting to know under what constraints (ii) is equivalent to (i) (or (iii) or (iv)).

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a partial answer.

Let $Z$ be an infinite subset of $Y$, let $\kappa=|Z|$, and suppose that $Z$ has no complete accumulation point in $X$. Then each $x\in X$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $|U_x\cap Z|<\kappa$. Let

$$\mathscr{F}=\{F\subseteq Z:|Z\setminus F|<\kappa\}\;;$$

$\mathscr{F}$ is a filter on $Z$. Let

$$D=\{\langle F,z\rangle\in\mathscr{F}\times Z:z\in F\}\;,$$

and for $\langle F_0,z_0\rangle,\langle F_1,z_1\rangle\in D$ write $\langle F_0,z_0\rangle\preceq \langle F_1,z_1\rangle$ if and only if $F_0\supseteq F_1$; then $\langle D,\preceq\rangle$ is a directed set, and

$$\nu:D\to Y:\langle F,z\rangle\mapsto z$$

is a net in $Y$.

Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary. Let $F_0=Z\setminus U_x$, and let $z_0\in F$ be arbitrary; $|Z\setminus F_0|=|U_x\cap Z|<\kappa$, so $\langle F_0,z_0\rangle\in D$. But if $\langle F,z\rangle\in D$ and $\langle F_0,z_0\rangle\preceq\langle F,z\rangle$, then $z\in F\subseteq F_0=Z\setminus U_x$, so $\nu$ is not frequently in $U_x$. Thus, $x$ is not a cluster point of $\nu$, and $\nu$ therefore has no cluster point in $X$. This shows that (i) implies (ii).

I’ll have to give the opposite implication more thought, though I’m inclined to suspect that it’s false in general.

Comment: Nice filter construction! (One surely could directly avoid the transfer to the corresponding canonical net.) In case (ii) is strictly weaker than (i) it would be interesting ti know whether there are some (possibly weak) separation constraints on $X$ under which equivalence of (i) and (ii) does hold.

Comment: @yadaddy: Yes, I did the translation back to nets simply because you’d stated the conditions that we. I’ve not made much progress, positive or negative, on the other direction, but I’m still thinking about it. It’s an interesting problem.